# IntelliJ and internationalisation: accented characters

Tags: java, internationalization, intellij-idea

I have a java application which has a GUI in both English and French, using the standard Java internationalisation services. I wrote it in JBuilder 2005 on an old machine, and recently upgraded, which has meant changing IDEs. I have finally settled on IntelliJ.

However, it doesn't seem able to handle the accented characters in my ListResourceBundle descendants which contain French. When I first created the IntelliJ project and added my source (which I did manually, to be sure nothing weird was going on behind the scenes), I noticed that all the accented characters had been changed into pairs of characters such as √©.  I went through the code and corrected all of these, and assumed that the problem was fixed.

But I find on running the (rebuilt) project that the pairs of characters are still showing, instead of the accented characters that I see in my code!

Can someone who has done internationalisation in IntelliJ please tell me what I need to do to fix this?

PS: I'm on the Mac.

Comment: +1 for adoring IntelliJ IDE.  If it were not for that IDE I'd already have switched from Java to another language ;)

Comment: <bows>  I call 'em as I see 'em! :-)
To be perfectly honest, I was living reasonably comfortably with the foibles of NetBeans...UNTIL it started randomly deleting .class files after compilation.  All the forums can say, it seems, is that it's a known intermittent bug...and none of the workarounds did it for me.
I'm actually glad; it led me to IntelliJ, which thus far has almost no foibles! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things --

First, make sure your files are being stored as UTF, and that your source control supports the encoding.

Second, consider using the resource bundle editing support built into IntelliJ http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/i18n_support.html

Comment: Wow, I just took a look at the I18n support in IntelliJ!  Yet another reason to be totally in love with this product.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Also, I don't know how to do what you suggest in your first sentence.  Can you be a bit more specific, please?

Comment: Sorry I was sleepy when I responded. Check out [http://jetbrains.dzone.com/articles/new-approach-encoding] for setting file encoding.

The advice I wish to convey is to be very deliberate about file encoding in your project. You can choose to use 1521 and use escapes for everything, or use a UTF8 and embed the actual characters in your code. As @openCage has indicated, properties files will still be locked into ascii-only, but with i18n, my experience has been that test cases, then some code invariably starts needing to use non-ascii characters as well.

Comment: WRT source control, some source control systems misbehave when they expect a text file encoding that doesn't support all the characters you write without escaping. Diff and merge etc have issues.

If your team is entirely US based, 1521 is not a bad choice. If you are geographically spread out, UTF is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks...sorry, I was also sleepy when I responded!  I should have mentioned that currently I don't have any source control.  This isn't as shocking as it might seem -- I'm the only developer.  It's on my wish list to set up one day :-)  When I do, I'll keep your comments in mind.
BTW I got the thing working tonight, set the file encodings and everyone's happy.  I chose UTF8 so that I can see the actual text in my files.  Feels better that way.  On to the next problem! :-)
Have a good weekend

Answer (score 0):

Java resource bundles should only hold ascii and Unicode escape codes
see [http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/].

e.g. \u00d6ffnen for German Öffnen.

The command line tool native2ascii converts from your native format to ascii plus unicode escape codes. It is a bit of a hassle but not an Intellij but a Java problem.

Note: I use Intellij on a Mac to create programs localized in English, German and Japanese.

Comment: Thanks...I tried this, and now instead of é I have "\u221a\u00a9" in the file, but when I run the program, I still get √© !!!
Help??